# If $X_n\to X$ a.e. it does not follow that $\mu_n(P)\to \mu(P)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X_n\to X$ a.e. and $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ are the p.m.'s of $X_n$ and $X$, it does not follow that $\mu_n(P)\to \mu(P)$ even for all intervals $P$.

I am having trouble coming up with an example that illustrates this. Why does Egoroff's theorem not guarantee that $\mu_n(P)\to \mu(P)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the measures we have in this problem.
We are working on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ so when we say $X_n \to X$ a.s., we mean  $\mathbb{P}$ almost surely. Then we have the laws $\mu_n$ of $X_n$ and $\mu$ of $X$.

Egorov's Theorem tells us we may find a set of $\mathbb{P}$ measure at least $1-\epsilon$ on which $X_n \to X$ uniformly. For sake of argument, suppose we could find a set of $\mathbb{P}$ measure $1$ on which $X_n \to X$ uniformly. Great, now what? The point is that the measure $\mathbb{P}$ isn't really related to $\mu_n = \mathbb{P}\circ X_n^{-1}$ since $X_n^{-1}$ can do whatever it pleases with sets before $\mathbb{P}$ sees them.

Here is a trivial example which demonstrates the conclusion may fail for an interval: If $X_n = 1/n$ for all $n$ with probability $1$, and $P=(0,1]$ then $\mu_n(P)=1 \not\to 0 = \mu(P)$.